# Identify iPhone users iTunes Store region?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, itunes

I'm looking to add the iTunes search api into one of my apps to return media.

I want to direct the user into their local Store instead of the default US one, e.g.

http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?term=some+media&country=UK

Is there a way to detect the users default store region in code?

many thanks
Nik

Comment: Reverse geolocation might be the only option - curious if there are other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [iTunes Link Maker](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/) it looks like they just sub in the country code to generate the country specific link.

Example:

> [http://itunes.apple.com/**mx**/app/foursquare/id306934924?mt=8&uo=4](http://itunes.apple.com/mx/app/foursquare/id306934924?mt=8&uo=4)

If you swap "mx" for us"

> [http://itunes.apple.com/**us**/app/foursquare/id306934924?mt=8&uo=4](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/foursquare/id306934924?mt=8&uo=4)

You get directed appropriately, therefore you should be able to use the following code to get the country code and sub it in.

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSString *foursquareAppStoreLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/%@/app/foursquare/id306934924?mt=8&uo=4", countryCode];
```

So assuming your link structure works the same way you could swap in the country code for `country=`

```
NSString *mySearchStringLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?term=some+media&country=%@", countryCode];
```

Comment: thank you! didn't realise NSLocale has country codes as well.